# How can I get correct court name from a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to get the court name from the string. However I have problem of locating it. Generally it lies within the first occurrence of brackets but may lies in second occurrence. So, I am trying to loop through an array to check the court name and if doesn't match any court names then print second occurrence. Here is the code:

```
$string='<b>Yara
Pilbara Fertilisers Pty Ltd [formerly known as Burrup Fertilisers Pty Ltd] v
Oswal (No. 8)</b> (FCA) - cross-vesting - Federal Court
proceedings transferred to Supreme Court of Victoria';

preg_match_all('/\(([^\)]*)\)/', $string, $matches);
    $all_courts=array("HCA","FCAFC","FCA","NSWCA","NSWSC","VCA","QCA","QSC","SASCFC","SASC","TSCA","TSC","WASCA","WASC","ACTCA","ACTSC","NTCA","NTSC");
$court_name=$matches[1][0];

        for($i=0;$i<count($all_courts);$i++)
        {
            if($all_courts[$i]!=$court_name)
            {
                $court_name=$matches[1][1];
            }

        }

echo $court_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you logic does not do what you want. It will always use the second parentheses, because $court_name will fail to match one of the values in $all_courts. You need to reverse this logic, e.g.\

```
if (!in_array($court_name, $all_courts)) {
    $court_name = $matches[1][1];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, bobdye.. this is what I wanted .. thanks a lot

Comment: hi, also can i get the index no. of the matching position?

Comment: $match = array_search($court_name, $all_courts) will give you the matching index.